# Best approach to manage roles in mvc 5 with windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I’m building an intranet based app as follows and need advice on the best way to manage user roles.

1. MVC 5 windows authentication intranet app.
2. Cannot use AD for roles will need to manage in with the app.
3. Only 3 roles, admin, supervisor, user that would be maintained in the app.
4. Ability to add/remove users to roles
5. Will use AD to get users name and email then persist within the app.
6. I’m using Entity framework 6 and sql server (this won’t change)

I’m unsure to create my own custom methods to manage roles as oppose to using the asp.net identity approach or any other method.

I'm thinking that as it is a relatively simple app I may just utilise my own methods?

Comment: Here's a good overview. http://www.typecastexception.com/post/2014/04/20/ASPNET-MVC-and-Identity-20-Understanding-the-Basics.aspx#The-Heart-of-it-All---ApplicationDbContext

Comment: OK thanks Steve I will read through this

Answer (score 1):

Hmm,

It's work, but if it were me I would use Windows Identity Foundation (WIF 4.5).  I would create a Custom Security Token Service and Security Token Configuration class.

First:

Build two tables in EF called Roles and UsersInRoles.

Roles

1. RoleId (auto increment)
2. Role (varchar(255))

Users In Roles

1. UserName (varchar(255), Unique, Primary Key)
2. RoleId (Foreign Key Role -> RoleId)

Wif:

Step 1:

Create a separate Project for building the Login Site, a new Empty MVC Site.  configure the web.config to use NTLM for authentication and remove anonymous access for it.  Give it a url like login.mysite.com.

Create the STS, STS Configuration, and a CertificateUtil:

```
public class XYZSecurityTokenServiceConfiguration : SecurityTokenServiceConfiguration
{
    static readonly object syncRoot = new object();
    static string stsKey = "XYZSecurityTokenServiceConfiguration";


    public static XYZSecurityTokenServiceConfiguration Current
    {
        get
        {
            HttpApplicationState httpAppState = HttpContext.Current.Application;
            XYZSecurityTokenServiceConfiguration myConfiguration = httpAppState.Get(stsKey) as XYZSecurityTokenServiceConfiguration;
            if (myConfiguration != null)
            {
                return myConfiguration;
            }
            lock (syncRoot)
            {
                myConfiguration = httpAppState.Get(stsKey) as XYZSecurityTokenServiceConfiguration;
                if (myConfiguration == null)
                {
                    myConfiguration = new XYZSecurityTokenServiceConfiguration();
                    httpAppState.Add(stsKey, myConfiguration);
                }
                return myConfiguration;
            }
        }
    }

    public XYZSecurityTokenServiceConfiguration() : base("XYZPassiveSTS", CertificateUtil.SigningCreds)
    {
        this.SecurityTokenService = typeof(TLCSecurityTokenService);
    }
}


public class XYZSecurityTokenService : SecurityTokenService
{
    public XYZSecurityTokenService(SecurityTokenServiceConfiguration configuration)
        : base(configuration)
    {                        
    }

    void ValidateAppliesTo(EndpointReference appliesTo)
    {
        if (appliesTo == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("appliesTo");
        }
    }

    protected override Scope GetScope(ClaimsPrincipal principal, RequestSecurityToken request)
    {
        ValidateAppliesTo(request.AppliesTo);

        Scope scope = new Scope(
            request.AppliesTo.Uri.OriginalString,
            SecurityTokenServiceConfiguration.SigningCredentials);
        scope.TokenEncryptionRequired = false;

        scope.ReplyToAddress = scope.AppliesToAddress;
        //scope.ReplyToAddress = request.ReplyTo;

        return scope;
    }

    protected override ClaimsIdentity GetOutputClaimsIdentity(ClaimsPrincipal principal, RequestSecurityToken request, Scope scope)
    {
        //We Can Add Additonal Claims Here!
        ClaimsIdentity claims = new ClaimsIdentity();
        claims.AddClaims(principal.Claims);
        string userName = principal.Identity.Name;

        //Use EF To get user's roles by userName,

        var roles = DBContext.GetRolesForUser(userName);
        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
           Claim roleClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.Role, ClaimValueTypes.String);
           claims.AddClaims(roleClaim);
        }
    }
}

public class CertificateUtil
{
    #region Fields
    private const string SIGNING_CERTIFICATE_NAME = "CN=TokenSigningCert";
    private const string ENCRYPTING_CERTIFICATE_NAME = "CN=TokenSigningCert";
    private static SigningCredentials _signingCreds = null;
    private static EncryptingCredentials _encryptingCreds = null;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public static SigningCredentials SigningCreds
    {
        get
        {
            if (_signingCreds == null)
                _signingCreds = new X509SigningCredentials(CertificateUtil.GetCertificate(StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.LocalMachine, SIGNING_CERTIFICATE_NAME));
            return _signingCreds;
        }
    }
    public static EncryptingCredentials EncryptingCreds
    {
        get
        {
            if (_encryptingCreds == null)
                _encryptingCreds = new X509EncryptingCredentials(CertificateUtil.GetCertificate(StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.LocalMachine, ENCRYPTING_CERTIFICATE_NAME));
            return _encryptingCreds;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the certificate from a specific store/location/subject.
    /// </summary>
    private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(StoreName name, StoreLocation location, string subjectName)
    {
        X509Store store = new X509Store(name, location);
        X509Certificate2Collection certificates = null;
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        try
        {
            X509Certificate2 result = null;

            //
            // Every time we call store.Certificates property, a new collection will be returned.
            //
            certificates = store.Certificates;

            for (int i = 0; i < certificates.Count; i++)
            {
                X509Certificate2 cert = certificates[i];

                if (cert.SubjectName.Name.ToLower() == subjectName.ToLower())
                {
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("More than one certificate was found for subject Name {0}", subjectName));
                    }

                    result = new X509Certificate2(cert);
                }
            }

            if (result == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("No certificate was found for subject Name {0}", subjectName));
            }

            return result;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (certificates != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < certificates.Count; i++)
                {
                    X509Certificate2 cert = certificates[i];
                    cert.Reset();
                }
            }

            store.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

In the Login site, you'll also need a controller to handle logging in and logging out.

Now, you'll be using NTLM, so any request to the site will be authenticated, if you turned off Anonymous access they can't get to the site without logging in with NTLM.

As such your controller only needs to do Process Request,

```
if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    return RedirectToAction("SomethingBroke");

CasPrincipal cp = User as CasPrincipal;
ClaimsPrincipal p = new ClaimsPrincipal(cp.Identity);
               FederatedPassiveSecurityTokenServiceOperations.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request, p, WIF.TLCSecurityTokenServiceConfiguration.Current.CreateSecurityTokenService(), System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response);
```

WIF is driven by query string parameters, and different parameters control what Process Request does.  If the Query has the wssignin parameter then it logs in and redirects back to the main site.  If it has wssignout, it signs out and redirects back.

Now, back in your main site, add web.cofnig entries to depend on the wif login site,

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </configSections>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <add name="WSFederatedAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration saveBootstrapContext="true">
      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <trustedIssuers>
          <!-- Use MMC and the Certificate Snapin to get the thumbprint for your certificate.  It will be different on other machines and this value might not work as is from source control.-->
          <add thumbprint="97f983a05587253b6835d1bd0062000c5d1f398d" name="TokenSigningCert" />
        </trustedIssuers>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
      <audienceUris mode="Never" />
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration identityConfigurationName="">
      <serviceCertificate>
        <certificateReference x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="TokenSigningCert" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPeople" />
      </serviceCertificate>
      <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="http://login.example.com" realm="http://example.com" requireHttps="false" />
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" mode="Default">
        <chunkedCookieHandler chunkSize="2000" />
      </cookieHandler>
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>  
</configuration>
```

Finally, in your main site you need a controller that handles login and logout.

You do that with

```
                //To Log In
            FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.RedirectToIdentityProvider("MYSiteIDYouMakeUpHere", "TheUrlToReturnToAfterLoginHere", true);

            //ToLogOut
            var issuer = FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.WsFederationConfiguration.Issuer;
            var signOutUrl = WSFederationAuthenticationModule.GetFederationPassiveSignOutUrl(issuer, "returnurlhere", null);
            Redirect(signOutUrl);
```

Comment: Sorry, that answer is only half complete, ran out of time, but that does show how to get roles from your app and issue them as claims during the login process.

Comment: HI Ryios thanks for your reply.   Yes  I will digest this.   Users won't need to login though as its an intranet app.

Comment: Well, they still login, it just might happen seamlessly.  You can still do that on the login site, they just won't see it, it will happen fast.

Comment: Also WIF might be overkill...  You could do it much more simple just using a RoleProvider and using the AD UserPrincipal for the user name.  However I consider RoleProvider's to be obsolete and try not to recommend people to use them.  In fact I don't think they are even included in .Net Core 5.

Comment: Also WIF is claims based, so you can create custom claim types and issue as many claims as you want.  For example, you could create a department claim type and issue one to the logged in user for the employee department they are in.  Then you can secure areas of the intranet to people in specific departments.

Comment: Thanks again Ryios - appreciate your replies